# Is it possible to have a second screen device launch an application on Google TV?

Tags: android, google-tv

I've been reading the AnyMot protocol and the fling is mentioned wherein a second screen app can launch the YouTube app.  Could a tablet application launch say the Flixter, Pandora or the Goolge Music app without it being a remote control emulator. If so would the AnyMot protocol be what's used?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Anymote is a very much adequate for that.  If, you want to do an app like "Able Remote", you'll need to put a small app on the TV which will tell you what apps are present.  But for what your asking, it's doable w/ just Anymote.

Comment: Thank you Les, can you please provide any insight as to how my app can determine what other apps are on the platform.  I'm very new to Android development.  Once my app determines what other apps are on the box can my app launch them?  Can my app be instructed to launch them via anymot protocols.

Comment: Good to ask that as another question.

Comment: Also @TKPhillyBurb is this answered your question you should mark it as 'answered'